# How to upload a file in Nuxtjs project's 'static' directory using axios?

Tags: node.js, upload, axios, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I want to save some `.xml.gz` files in Nuxt project's `static` directory on the response of an axios request.

I have an api endpoint which sends this file to the nuxt, but I don't know how should I save it in the `static` directory, so that later I can access and download that file publicly from nuxt's url by doing `www.foobar.com/sitemap-1.xml.gz`

The thing is, I can't keep these .xml.gz files in the nuxt project itself while hosting the frontend because the .xml.gz file keeps getting updated after every 15 days, so my plan is to hit the api endpoint from nuxt after every 15 days, store it in `static` folder, and access them publicly for next 15 days.

Also to mention, I'm using Nuxtjs as an SSR with a nodejs server, so is it possible to use some node package to save the file in nuxt static dir?

I'm open to any ideas, Thank you.

Comment: How do you build your page? I would suggest that before you start `$ nuxt generate`, you write a little node.js script, which fetches your files from the API and stores it within your static folder.

you could then either call a build hook url every 15 days manually or use a cron job or so to call that build hook.
Do you think that would be feasible in your case?
(We do something similar, where we save some crucial information from an API in a json file within the static folder,which can then be loaded into vuex store after app initiation)

Answer (score 2):

For a similar issue, I used [custome middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/#custom-server-middleware).

This will use the server which Nuxt uses to serve files and perform SSR. It will be easy for you to store files from these routes as the `static` folder will be easily available from these routes.